# Checking if document library (list) exists takes too long

Tags: csom, query, sharepoint-library

I need to check if specific document library exists on sharepoint site and I don't know the title of the library, because it is being created dynamically. The only thing I know is `RootFolder.Name` property of the library, which is also the part of the url.

As libraries collection of the site is pretty big (~20k records) it takes about 90 sec to execute the following code:

```
public static ClientContext ctx2010 = SharepointHelper.GetInstance(2010);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lists_ = ctx2010.LoadQuery(
        ctx2010.Web.Lists.Where(
            l => l.RootFolder.Name == "10016193"));

    ctx2010.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

As I understand, this query retrieves all libraries first, then applies the limitation of 'where' clause.

**Is there any way to improve performance of the query?**

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? 2010 or 2013 ?

Comment: @GautamSheth, Sharepoint 2010, but CSOM API version 16.xxx